# Workflow copy attribute in Geocortex Viewer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, geocortex, data-transfer

Is there a way to copy a attribute from a feature and paste it into a other feature attribute with a workflow?

ArcMap has a internal Tool spatial adjustment where this idea is possible with the button Attribute Transfer tool.

Is this possible in geocortex viewer with a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible.
Workflows can invoke C# DLLs and import ESRI.ArcGIS namespace ,
so in theory everything is possible. 
You will need to have the target layer editable (obviously).

Best practice would be:

1. clearly document the layer names and attributes
2. Perform the SQL statements manually to validate the syntax
3. If you can, write the sequence as if you were coding it in C# invoking ESRI.Arcgis libraries
4. Write up the Workflow in Geocortex workflow designer